# Non subscription based firewalls

Tags: networking, firewall

Looking for a one-time purchase, or free Firewall application to run on Windows 10.

**Requested Features**

- Able to monitor active connections, providing both Source and Destination IP Address;
- Allow me to monitor how much traffic has been sent/received per host/client application;
- Ability to block/allow connections based on host, IP Address (destination) or port usage;
- Ability to identify a change in software, and reprompt for access to the internet.

Previously I used [Outpost Firewall](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Outpost_Firewall_Pro) but it has been discontinued. The only other candidate at the moment is [Glasswire](https://www.glasswire.com/).

Comment: was my answer sufficient? If so please mark it so.

Comment: Any updates here, drakth?

Comment: I decided to go with Glasswire, other than Comodo, couldnt find a non-subscription option.

Comment: pleaae make an answer then :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I finally decided for Glasswire since i couldnt find any other than Comodo.

Comment: Please explain how Glasswire fits each of the requirements in your question. That's how this site works. Thanks! http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/356/what-is-required-for-an-answer-to-be-high-quality

Answer (score 1):

Whilst I am unsure if you simply want a free solution, or a one-time purchase of versioning (which is rare), I suggest **Comodo Firewall**.

[Comodo Firewall](https://personalfirewall.comodo.com/) can be installed separately, or as part of the "Comodo Security Suite". The product feature page outlines the following *free* tools:

Intuituve pop-up for applications attempting to connect to a foreign network, the port and if TCP/UDP:

[image: Comodo Pop-Up]

Further inspection of the application PIDS, traffic and amount of data used can be investigated as well:

[image: Process Activity List]

The application also allows multiple profiles for the type of network you're connected to, and each profile can have different rulesets to abide by:

[image: Profile Configuration]

You can even drill down per rule in each zone to specifically set rules per process:

[image: Application Rules]

Which can then be summarised in a simple widget for use:

[image: Widget]